# How do you pass a variable to strtotime?

Tags: php

I need to do a difference of two dates that have been saved as variables:

```
$init = "2015-05-10 12-04-58";
$datetime = "2015-05-10 12-07-18";
```

However, when I attempt to use strtotime to convert each variable to time, both come up blank:

```
$t1 = strtotime("$init"); // results in empty $t1
$t2 = strtotime("$datetime"); // results in empty $t2
$diff = $t2 - $t1; // some math
```

I expected double-quotes to do the trick. What is missing?

Comment: As a side note, why not use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime).

Comment: Reading never hurts: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: You should use the DateTime Class.

Answer (score 1):

strtotime can't parse the format you used. If you use "Y-m-d H:i:s" you will have better success.

valid formats are listed at: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: That works perfectly. Tx

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to work with dates in **PHP >= 5.2.0** is using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), i.e.:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon'); // check the list of supported timezones http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

$startRaw = '2015-05-10 12-04-58';
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H-i-s', $startRaw );

$endRaw = date("Y-m-d H-i-s");
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H-i-s', $endRaw );

$diff = $start->diff($end);

echo 'Difference: ' . $diff->format('%H Hours, %d days') . "\n";
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/2Tfhfo

---

```
format
```

> The following characters are recognized in the `format` parameter
>   string. Each format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (%).

```
% Literal % % 
Y Years, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0 01, 03 
y Years, numeric 1, 3 
M Months, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0 01, 03, 12 
m Months, numeric 1, 3, 12 
D Days, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0 01, 03, 31 
d Days, numeric 1, 3, 31 
a Total amount of days 4, 18, 8123 
H Hours, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0 01, 03, 23 
h Hours, numeric 1, 3, 23 
I Minutes, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0 01, 03, 59 
i Minutes, numeric 1, 3, 59 
S Seconds, numeric, at least 2 digits with leading 0 01, 03, 57 
s Seconds, numeric 1, 3, 57 
R Sign "-" when negative, "+" when positive -, + 
r Sign "-" when negative, empty when positive -,
```

Learn more about [The DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)